# breaks in latex is giving extra tab

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, line-spacing

I am trying to learn Latex, I have to solve an assignment that involves BNF grammar rules.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{syntax}

\title{Hello world }
\author{Buk Lau }
\date{October, 28 2016}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Second Problem}
We have the following BNF grammar rule:

\begin{grammar}
<pop> ::= [<bop> , <pop>] | <bop>\\
<bop> ::= <boop> | (<pop> )\\
<boop> ::= x|y|z
\end{grammar}

\section{Conclusion}
``I always thought something was fundamentally wrong with the universe'' \citep{adams1995hitchhiker}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Here is my output:

[image]

No errors are given on compilation. However, there is an extra tab added after the break (on the next two statements):

[image]

Why is it happening? What can I do to fix that? Furthermore, how can centralize the three statements (Not really part of this question, but I'd appreciate if you can tell me how)?

Answer (score 2):

The package manual `texdoc syntax` states that separate production rules should be separated by blank lines and that `\\` is for continuing long rules over a line (hence the indentation)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{syntax}

\title{Hello world }
\author{Buk Lau }
\date{October, 28 2016}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Second Problem}
We have the following BNF grammar rule:

\begin{grammar}
<pop> ::= [<bop> , <pop>] | <bop>

<bop> ::= <boop> | (<pop> )

<boop> ::= x|y|z
\end{grammar}

\section{Conclusion}
``I always thought something was fundamentally wrong with the universe'' \citep{adams1995hitchhiker}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This will add two line breaks. I don't want this to happen. I only want it to return line.

Comment: @BukLau As noted further down the page that describes the enviornment use `\setlength\grammarparsep{0pt}` to customise the length between rules

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `syntax`, you can define something similar via [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings).

There is some `literate` changes to improve the layout, including using `\vcentcolon` for a better preview of `::=`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,mathtools}

\lstnewenvironment{grammar}[1][]
  {\lstset{
    %basicstyle = \ttfamily,
    numbers = none,
    fontadjust = true,
    flexiblecolumns = true,
    keepspaces = false,
    literate = {<}{$\langle$}1
               {>}{$\rangle$}1
               {::=}{$\vcentcolon\vcentcolon=$}3
   }}
  {}

\begin{document}

\noindent
We have the following BNF grammar rule:
\begin{grammar}
<pop> ::= [<bop> , <pop>] | <bop>
<bop> ::= <boop> | (<pop>)
<boop> ::= x|y|z
\end{grammar}

\end{document}
```